# Android surfaceview animation

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve animation on a surfaceview. But, my surfaceview's background is transparent, and I can't clear away the pixels of last frame. 
Can I achieve some animations on transparent surfaceview? Maybe I only use 'Animation' class on a view. 
Thanks!

---

Maybe I didn't describe the question clearly. I want to achieve a animation, but surfaceview can't refresh last graph.It looks like the picature.

[image]

The background is transparent. I known draw canvas with color can clean the last drawn graph. But its background is transparent, the method doesn't achieve refresh.
Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Watch the following code, it worked for me:

```
Paint clearPaint = new Paint();

public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
}

public void drawMethod(){
    Canvas canvas = this.getHolder().lockCanvas();

    canvas.drawPaint(clearPaint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmap, null, yourBitmapRect, null);

    this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

You have have to put your SurfaceView on top in Z order and set PixelFormat to transparent. That will make your SurfaceView transparent (this part you've done, as you wrote).
Then you have to fill your surface with a transparent paint before each new drawing. This "special" paint needs to be set like so:

```
clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is important for me.

Comment: Great answer! Never forget the setZOrderOnTop(true)!

Comment: To be more precise `clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));` because there is a `AvoidXfermode.Mode` so be care at import or write explicit `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`

Answer (score 3):

you can try to `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)` at the start of every draw()

Comment: This is actually the recommended method from the Android documentation, +1.